# JBoss EAP Container Fails to Start

Tags: docker, jboss, containers

When I run the following Dockerfile, the container responds with an error and exits.

If I comment out `COPY`, the container starts with no error.

Do I need to configure something else to get the container to start and deploy the app?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/jboss-eap-7/eap73-openjdk11-openshift-rhel8
COPY containerPocApp.war /opt/eap/standalone/data/content/containerPocApp.war
EXPOSE 8080
```

Error:

```
ERROR Error applying /tmp/cli-configuration-script-1595016439.cli CLI script.

00:00:00,000 INFO [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 1.10.0.Final-redhat-00001

Cannot start embedded server: WFLYEMB0022: Cannot invoke 'start' on embedded process: WFLYSRV0231: Could not read or create the server UUID in file: /opt/eap/standalone/data/kernel/process-uuid: /opt/eap/standalone/data/kernel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add r/w permission for Jboss dir to the root group , the error indicates a r/w permission errors

try to add this to your `Dockerfile`

```
USER root
RUN chgrp -R 0 $JBOSS_HOME && chmod -R g+rw $JBOSS_HOME
```